# Oracle SQL Developer - taking a long time to retrieve the status of the sessions

Tags: sql, oracle, session, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

When I try to monitor the sessions in Oracle SQL Developer version 3.1.07, it retrieves all the session in a second.

But when I try to monitor the sessions in Oracle SQL Developer version 4.0.2, it is taking a long time to retrieve the sessions list.  I am just staring at the below image for a long time.

Is there any way to speed up this process

[image: the developer is waiting for a long time to list]

Comment: Well, see what the two queries are different that are being executed?

Comment: The newer version might be making different calls than than older version. I don't use SQL Developer so I can't point you directly  but TOAD has something called the SQL Tracker which allows you to monitor all calls to the database (including those initiated from the TOAD GUI). If you can find the equivalent for SQL Developer then you could verify that the two versions perform the exact same operations. If so that might point to some kind of driver issue.

Comment: we go against the GV$ views now instead of V$ - which usually won't make a difference unless you're on RAC. Are you on a RAC instance?

Comment: @hillbillyToad Yes, I am on RAC instance. Is there anything which we can edit in the Preferences so that I can get the results faster. It is taking minimum of 2 mins to retrieve all the sessions

Comment: @OldProgrammer As hillbillyToad points out, the only difference is that, in the old developer V$ views are used and in the new version GV$ views are used to retrieve the results

Comment: I think what probably needs to happen is start a conversation with your dba on why those views are so slow to query..perhaps the data dictionary stats are out of date.